# Move FileTable data from a database to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to move `FileTable` data from a `Database` to another.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929144.aspx

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

If the database is configured for non-transactional access, you can simply create a new file table in the target database and move the files from the source file table share to the new file table share.

Answer (score 0):

If table having same columns in both database.
export that table alone from database and goto another database, import the exported file.

Comment: This is a FileTable in Sql Server 2012 not a table.